# Was Jack Vance's fictional Cosmopolitan supposed to be a future version of the pre-1965 Cosmo?

Tags: jack-vance, demon-princes

In Jack Vance's *[Demon Princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Princes)* novels, there are often epigraphs beginning the chapters.  Frequently these are drawn from a general interest magazine that ultimately plays an important role in the story.  (After making a vast sum of money in the second book, *[The Killing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_Machine)*, the protagonist Kirth Gersen eventually buys the magazine.)

What is noticeable is that the name of the magazine changes between the second and third books, from *Cosmopolitan* to *Cosmopolis*.  Out-of-universe, the reason for this is fairly obvious.  The first and second volumes, *[Star King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_King)* and *The Killing Machine*, were written in 1964.  Then next year, Helen Gurley Brown became the editor-in-chief of the real *Cosmopolitan*, and transformed it from a general interest and literary magazine to to the women's magazine it is known as today.  By 1967, when the third book, *[The Palace of Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Palace_of_Love)*, was written, the new *Cosmo* had become a cultural phenomenon, and Vance presumably felt obligated to change the name.

What I wondered as I read these books (long after their publication) was whether Vance had intended *Cosmopolitan* to be a far-future version of the actual pre-1965 general interest magazine.  Or did he just choose the name, without knowing or thinking about the real-world magazine?  Did Vance every talk about this explicitly?